# Find and replace characters in links

Tags: html

I would like to replace character "_" inside links but only inside href"..." (links have with different "title" and some of them have "target" blank )
 
...
.
I tried with dreamweaver "find and replace" but not succeed (don't know how to do it).
Can anyone please help?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: a href="../bla_bla1__" title="any text1" ...[a link] a href="../bla_bla9__" title="any text9"

Comment: Are you trying to do this dynamically on runtime with Javascript or from within your editor? If it's the latter, an editor with regex find and replace support could come in handy.

Comment: I tried with dreamweaver find and replace, but no succeed it.

Comment: so, instead of  a href="../bla_bla1__" title="any text1"   I would like to have:     a href="../bla-bla1--" title="any text1"